# AD client won't getIP address from DHCP server

Tags: networking, active-directory, ip, dhcp, ipv4

Server is running Windows Server 2016. Client has Windows 8. Unless my client has a static IP address, it cannot communicate with the AD. My DHCP server won't give my client an IP addresses, and I don't know why. I want my DHCP server to automatically give an IP address to systems that are connected to it so that I don't have to manually configure the client's IP address for every client I add to the domain.Currently, my DHCP server is giving me an error. "The DHCP service is not servicing any DHCPipv4 clients because none of the active network interfaces have statically configured IPv4 addresses, or there are no active interfaces." Does this mean that when I am using AD, my clients must use a static IP address? If so, how to I change that?

Answer (score 1):

> The DHCP service is not servicing any DHCPipv4 clients because none of the active network interfaces have statically configured IPv4 addresses, or there are no active interfaces

This message says that you must assign a static IP address on your DHCP **Server**. You can use the following procedure: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755277(v=ws.11).aspx

Answer (score -1):

Add DNS Ip to user (DNS-AD IP).Restart the DHCP service.